# Follow-up to Baby Rudin

Tags: analysis, reference-request, soft-question, self-learning

I would like to continue my study of analysis, albeit temporarily in self-study, and I was wondering what would be the best "sequel" to baby Rudin.  Thank you very much for your advice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not follow up with Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis? It contains real, complex and functional analysis all in one! Totally awesome!

Comment: Darn. I clicked on this question to say the same thing.

Comment: Are you wrongly doing some conflating here? Baby Rudin = Principles of Mathematical Analysis; Papa Rudin = Real and Complex Analysis; Grandpa Rudin = Functional Analysis; source: Wikipedia article on Walter Rudin: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Rudin

Answer (score 6):

I highly recommend Gerald Folland's *Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications*, which is one of the most student-friendly analysis texts out there.

Comment: Of course, if you like Rudin's style of writing (including his terseness), then I think Jasper's suggestion is very good, too: _Real and Complex Analysis_ is a great book.

Comment: Hi @jessemadnick, how would you compare Folland's Real Analysis book with Royden's book?

Comment: @User001: My personal opinion is that Royden is even friendlier and more elementary, whereas Folland assumes the reader is a little more mathematically mature.  But Folland is more thorough (which I really appreciate), and I think ultimately provides students with a stronger background.  I like both.